# Formatting h1, h2 in rmd/rmarkdown

Tags: css, r, r-markdown

With an external css file, I can change many items in an Rmd/html document, but some basic ones are overridden by inline css inserted by markdown (?).

```
.main-container {
....
h1 {
  font-size: 34px;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

So the only way to change h2 font size is by inserting the  code directly into the document, which is ugly:

```
---
output: 
  html_document:
    theme: cosmo
   # css: whatever.css # adding h2 here does not work
---

<style type = "text/css">
h2 {color: red;}
</style>

## R Markdown
```

Any better solution? Is it possible to suppress the above inline chunk?

Comment: you can use `!important` in you custom css to override

Comment: Using `!important` is not recommended, however, you can't have higher specificity in CSS than inline style AFAIK... you'd have to strip the inline style or use `!important` in [this fashion](https://css-tricks.com/override-inline-styles-with-css/): `element[style] { property: value !important; }`

Comment: I tried `h2[style] { color: blue !important; }` without effect. Did I get the syntax wrong?

Comment: @DieterMenne we should probably chat.

Answer (score 2):

This was fixed by JJAllaire in:

https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/652#event-600790015